# Asus express cache using windows 8

Tags: windows-8, drivers, ssd

I have this ASUS n551jw notebook. It came with windows 10 pre-installed.

However, I had to install windows 8 on it becuase some of the work related programs doesn't support windows 10.

While installing drivers, I noticed that express cache drivers were missing from offical drivers page of Asus. Instead there is a download for intel rapid storage technology drivers.

I guess I need to use this to utilise ssd part of my hard drive. However, I can't figure out how to enable this option, or check whether or not it is installed correctly.

Supposedly, after installing drivers, I should see settings for irst in my control panel, however, I don't see such setting.

How do I utilize ssd disk of ASUS n551jw using windows 8?

Comment: It is very likely if the machine came with Windows 10 then there are not compatible Windows 10 drivers that exist provided by ASUS.  `ASUS ExpressCache` and `Intel RST` are not identical.  You need to install the current and applicable `Intel Chipset Driver`, `Intel Management Engine Interface`, and `Intel Rapid Storage Technology`.  ASUS ExpressCache is a vendor specific implementation of what I presume is Intel's underline storage drivers.  You can locate all three drivers on Intel's website.

Comment: you should try to resolve incompatibility of your programs with windows 10 instead of forcing your machine to work with an OS it wasn't designed for. windows 10 has greater backwards compatibility compared to windows 8 so i think any software that runs on windows 8 can run on windows 10 too.

Comment: My comment was suppose to indicate there won't be **Windows 8** drivers for it.  The rest of the comment is accurate though.